# Network error when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, rest, google-app-engine, heroku, cors

Hello fellow developers and data scientists. I have a question about a problem with accessing the API deployed on the google app engine from the javascript app deployed on Heroku.

When I access my API link on google chrome, it works properly. However, when I use my javascript app deployed on Heroku to call my API link, it sometimes does not work and return me the network error. [CORS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dhOK.png)

I have followed the instruction on "https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref" to enable the CORS access on my app API  in the app.ymal file on google app engine as the following

runtime: python37instance_class: F4_1Ghandlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ‘*’

Similarly, I have also enabled the CORS access on my javascript app (React) deployed on Heroku as shown in the picture attached. [CORS enabled on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4w44.png) However, the problem still persists. I am not sure if it has to do with the way we set up our code or the google app engine server itself. If there is anything I could do besides what I have done I would love to hear that as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The instructions listed on the google cloud documents ([CORS Support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#cors-support)) apply only to static assets (such as images). However if you want to call your API (which consists of dynamic pages like Python scripts) you have to do the configuration on the Python side, by sending the appropriate headers from your scripts. Here's an example on how to do it by using a Flask extension called [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/api/v1/users")
def list_users():
  return "user example"
```

The way to do it on your own script really depends on your implementation.